Why will my Excel VSTO Add-In only load If Excel is run under Administrator
I have an Excel VSTO add-in which utilises nlog.  The nlog.config file is stored in the following folder:
C:\ProgramData\Company Name\Historian Client\Config
If I run Excel as non-admin, the Add-In fails to load with a run-time error attempting to access the nlog.config file.  If I run as Admin the Add-In loads and functions normally.  I had thought content under the ProgramData folder would be accessible by Add-In processes, however this appears not to be the case.  Is there a way that I can configure Windows security to allow this access?

Are you hardcoding the path or retrieving the base program data path and combine it with your custom subfolder names? The permission might also depend on who created the folder; do you force the folders if they don't exist? If yes, try to delete the folder and ensure your code recreates it when running as non-admin user.

Thanks Dmitry, that sorted it.  Seems logical in hindsight :-)
